# Is it possible to use React without rendering HTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if it's possible to use React for doing logic and sending data back to a javascript function, without rendering any html. The component I'm thinking of is something that you pass some data to, and it'll send data back to a javascript function outside of react. I know that can be done, and I've done that part myself, but I'm not sure how you would do this without rendering html as it is required. Is this even a practical use case for react?

Comment: React is a library for building views.  What features of React lead you to want to use it for your task?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As of React >= 16.2 it is possible to use any of these versions:

```
render() { 
   return false; 
}

render() { 
   return null; 
}

render() { 
   return []; 
}

render() { 
   return <React.Fragment></React.Fragment>; 
}

render() { 
   return <></>; 
}
```

Returning `undefined` does not work.

---

> The component I'm thinking of is something that you pass some data to,
>   and it'll send data back to a javascript function outside of react.

Why would you want to create a component for that? Most of the time a regular js function in an existing component can be enough.

One usecase is for exemple to setup a side-effect when component is mounted and tear it down when it unmounts. For exemple if you have a ReactNative mobile app with portrait orientation, you could imagine a `<Landscape/>` component, that, when mounted, would allow temporarily to display the app in landscape orientation, and when unmounted, orientation would be reset to app default. You can surely manage this orientation change on an existing component, but creating a dedicated component might be more handy and reusable.

Note that React can also run on the server side so I guess it is possible to use it in such a way that it doesn't involve any DOM modifications (but maybe only the virtual DOM computation).

Comment: Nope, `render()` method can't return an empty array or anything other than other React component.

Comment: It can return `null` or `false` as described in the documentation http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render

Comment: Indeed, looks like it is new in 0.11: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/07/17/react-v0.11.html#rendering-to-null

Comment: It looks like it will actually render out a <noscript>. This is can be somewhat problematic, for example a CSS block using .list-group-item:last-child

Comment: @Ray you'll need to use `:last-of-type` in that case.

Comment: Why return `false`?  Doesn't that imply `render()` is asking a binary question?  You should return `null` in this case, as that is what you want to render.

Comment: Stumbled across this while I was making one so to answer this question: "Why would you want to create a component for that? Isn't some regular javascript function enough?"

At least in my case, I get to use nice framework features that come with the architecture like using react-redux to connect the component to my state and pass in props as well as having propTypes. This may not be enough validation to some people - I'd love to hear opinions to the contrary.

Answer (score 22):

Just to clarify benno's comments. The [ReactComponent.render method doc](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render) states:

> You can also return `null` or `false` to indicate that you don't want anything rendered. Behind the scenes, React renders a `<noscript>` tag to work with our current diffing algorithm. When returning `null` or `false`, `this.getDOMNode()` will return `null`.

Answer (score 15):

It is possible. react-router is an example of a library with components not rendering HTML. See https://github.com/rackt/react-router

This is the Route component of react-fouter with a render method returning false:

```
const Route = React.createClass({

  statics: {
    createRouteFromReactElement
  },

  propTypes: {
    path: string,
    component,
    components,
    getComponent: func,
    getComponents: func
  },

  /* istanbul ignore next: sanity check */
  render() {
    invariant(
      false,
      '<Route> elements are for router configuration only and should not be rendered'
    )
  }

})
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is very much possible and very much useful, in case of lazy loading components.

Consider this example with react-router.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

function asyncComponent(getComponent) {
  return class AsyncComponent extends React.Component {
    static Component = null;
    state = { Component: AsyncComponent.Component };

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.state.Component) {
        getComponent().then(Component => {
          AsyncComponent.Component = Component
          this.setState({ Component })
        })
      }
    }
    render() {
      const { Component } = this.state
      if (Component) {
        return <Component {...this.props} />
      }
      return null
    }
  }
}

const Page1 = asyncComponent(() =>
  System.import('./Page1.js').then(module => module.default)
)
const Page2 = asyncComponent(() =>
  System.import('./Page2.js').then(module => module.default)
)
const Page3 = asyncComponent(() =>
  System.import('./Page3.js').then(module => module.default)
)

const ParentComponent = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <Link to="/page1">Page1</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
      <Link to="/page2">Page2</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
      <Link to="/page3">Page3</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <Route path="/page1" component={Page1}/>
      <Route path="/page2" component={Page2}/>
      <Route path="/page3" component={Page3}/>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```